# Comparing 3 objects JAVA

Tags: java

Could someone explain to me why the 3rd one is not working? The first one works and the second one does but not the third.

```
if(object1 != object2 && object1 != object3 && object2 != object3)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have 0 matches");
    }
    else if(object1 == object2 || object2 == object3 || object1 == object3)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have 1 match");
    }
    else if(object1 == object2 && object2 == object3 || object1 == object3 && object3 == object2)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have all matches");
```

Comment: you have to use `equals` to compare objects in Java

Comment: Comparing objects is done with `Object.equals(other)`. You're comparing references (in other words: you're checking for identity, not equality).

Comment: I'm sorry, I put object there for examples. I didn't mean to confuse anyone.

Answer (score 3):

```
object1 == object2 || object2 == object3 || object1 == object3
```

This condition will be true whether there's exactly one match *or* all conditions match, but since it comes first, you can never get to the third condition because the second condition already matched.

Switch the third condition to come before the second condition and you'll be fine.  Also, you don't need the `||` in the "all match" condition -- it doesn't matter what order you do the comparisons if they all match.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is being taken *instead* of the third. Whenever this is true:

```
if(object1 == object2 && object2 == object3 || object1 == object3 && object3 == object2)
```

Then this is also true:

```
if(object1 == object2 || object2 == object3 || object1 == object3)
```

And since it is an if-else, it will be taken first.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is wrong. try this...

```
if(object1 != object2 && object1 != object3 && object2 != object3)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have 0 matches");
    }
    else if(object1 == object2 && object2 != object3 || object1 == object3 && object3 != object2
            || object2 == object3 && object2 != object1)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have 1 match");
    }
    else if(object1 == object2 && object2 == object3)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have all matches");

    }
```